# Advertise multiple services with same srv

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have several simultaneously active services that have the same data type for both the Request and Response fields. Can I use the same .srv file for all of the services? Or should I create a uniquely named .srv file for each service (the contents of which would be identical)?

If it's technically acceptable to re-use the same .srv file, is it considered good or bad practice?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230013/advertise-multiple-services-with-same-srv/) by [Viggio](https://answers.ros.org/users/26379/viggio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes; you can re-use the same .srv for multiple services, and it's generally considered good practice.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0